# Highcharts xAxis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using a Highcharts for some charting specifically the [Spline with plot bands](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands). The associated jsfiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-plot-bands/).

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Wind speed during two days'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'May 31 and and June 1, 2015 at two locations in Vik i Sogn, Norway'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Wind speed (m/s)'
        },
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        alternateGridColor: null,
        plotBands: [{ // Light air
            from: 0.3,
            to: 1.5,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
            label: {
                text: 'Light air',
                style: {
                    color: '#606060'
                }
            }
        }, { // Light breeze
            from: 1.5,
            to: 3.3,
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            label: {
                text: 'Light breeze',
                style: {
                    color: '#606060'
                }
            }
        }, { // Gentle breeze
            from: 3.3,
            to: 5.5,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
            label: {
                text: 'Gentle breeze',
                style: {
                    color: '#606060'
                }
            }
        }, { // Moderate breeze
            from: 5.5,
            to: 8,
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            label: {
                text: 'Moderate breeze',
                style: {
                    color: '#606060'
                }
            }
        }, { // Fresh breeze
            from: 8,
            to: 11,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
            label: {
                text: 'Fresh breeze',
                style: {
                    color: '#606060'
                }
            }
        }, { // Strong breeze
            from: 11,
            to: 14,
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            label: {
                text: 'Strong breeze',
                style: {
                    color: '#606060'
                }
            }
        }, { // High wind
            from: 14,
            to: 15,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
            label: {
                text: 'High wind',
                style: {
                    color: '#606060'
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' m/s'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            lineWidth: 4,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 5
                }
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            pointInterval: 3600000, // one hour
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 4, 31, 0, 0, 0)
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Hestavollane',
        data: [0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5, 2.9, 1.9, 2.6, 1.6, 3, 4, 3.6, 4.5, 4.2, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 3.1, 2.7, 4, 2.7, 2.3, 2.3, 4.1, 7.7, 7.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.8, 8.6, 7.2, 9, 10.9, 11.5, 11.6, 11.1, 12, 12.3, 10.7, 9.4, 9.8, 9.6, 9.8, 9.5, 8.5, 7.4, 7.6]

    }, {
        name: 'Vik',
        data: [0, 0, 0.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 3.1, 3.1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1, 2.3, 1.9, 1.2, 0.7, 1.3, 0.4, 0.3]
    }],
    navigation: {
        menuItemStyle: {
            fontSize: '10px'
        }
    }
});
```

});

I need the chart to show time not to time - 50min (at minute intervals). That is to say the right most point of data is time = now and the left most is time - 50 min.

Adding the spline data is not a problem but I am having trouble adding he correct data for the xAxis.

The date data I have is in milliseconds (1456783080016000) but what is the best way to get this into the chart bearing in mind that this chart updates ever minute as must the xAxis.

Code that i have seen shows you can update it like so:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({categories:['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']}, true);
```

How do I add the date date to this update ?

My second part of this question is what is the role of the 
pointInterval & pointStart.

I am assuming the pointInterval is one minute or (60000ms) and the point  `pointStart: Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - 3000000)` which is time now minus 50 minutes (3000000ms).

This doesn't seem to be working so any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `xAxis.tickPositioner` and `xAxis.labels.formatter` to get the desired result. Snippet:

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 600000, // get every 10th tick
        tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
          var ticks = [],
              interval = this.tickInterval;

          while (max >= min) {
            ticks.push(max);
            max -= interval;
          }
          return ticks.reverse(); 
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            var max = this.axis.max,
                diff = max - this.value;

            if (diff === 0) {
                return 'Now';
            }
            return '-' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%M', diff) + 'mins';     
          }
        }
    },
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tdmjm9pn/1/

Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something similar to the following

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
      categories: [1373155200000, 1373241600000, 1373328000000, 1373414400000, 1373500800000, 1373587200000, 1373673600000, 1373760000000, 1373846400000, 1373932800000, 1374019200000, 1374105600000],
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          var d = new Date(this.value);
          return d.toDateString();
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
  });
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/7na7au4m/)

Comment: The issue there is it is only coming up with the date. Is it possible to get time with it? or just display time between date changes ?

Comment: Yes, but with just time and only a date if it changes.